Can I create a registry with a service from an external module within a controller that is in another module in Nest.js?
I have a main controller called MainController, when I call 'Put' and update a record, depending on certain cases within this function I need to call a function to create a new record of a service that is in another module: 'Secondary .service.ts', here is it possible to create an object and send it to that function to create a new record of another service?
Try this, when updating the main record, if everything is fine, I want to create a record from the other external service, try to create an object with the data that I need to send to the create function of that service but it gives me an error: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined.
@Put(':id')
async update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() data: UserDocument ) {
    let response = await this.userService.update(id, data);
    if (response.ok == 1) {
        // Find user register
        let user = await this.userService.findOne(+id);

        // Create object StoreMainDocument
        let storeMain: storeMainDocument
        storeMain.name = user.name;
        storeMain.url = user.path;
        storeMain.type = "Type";
        storeMain.user_id = user._id;

        console.log("storeMain", storeMain)

        // Send object and create register
        await this.storeMainService.create(storeMain);
    }
    return response;
}

This is the error obtained on the line: storeMain.name = user.name;

I am not sure if it is the correct way or to create the object of type "StoreMainDocument" which is what receives the function of the external service "this.storeMainService.create(storeMain)" it has to be done in another way.
This is the 'create' function of the external service that I am trying to use from the other controller:
public async create(storeMainDoc: StoreMain): Promise<StoreMain> {
    let nextCodeFromDb = await this.storeMainModel.findOne().sort({ code: -1 }).lean();
    if (!nextCodeFromDb) nextCodeFromDb = new StoreMain({code:0});
    storeMainDoc.code = nextCodeFromDb.code + 1;

    const createModel = await new this.storeMainModel(storeMainDoc);
    return await createModel.save();
}

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this. How can I fix it?

You're not initializing the storeMain variable:
let storeMain: storeMainDocument. That's why the error says you cannot set a property on undefined. The variable you declared still has undefined as value.
Initializing would look like this:
let storeMain: storeMainDocument = {
  name: user.name,
  url: user.path,
  ...and so on
}

Also I'm not sure if storeMainDocument is the correct type. Usually types start with a capital letter, but that's up to you.
